# chef application_ruby cookbook: unicorn is not restarted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chef-infra, unicorn, chef-recipe

I have the following application defined using application and application_ruby cookbooks:

```
application 'railsapp' do
  owner 'vagrant'
  group 'vagrant'
  path '/home/vagrant/railsapp'
  revision 'master'
  repository 'git@github.com:rohshall/railsreadings.git'
  migrate true
  rails do
    bundler true
    database do
      host 'localhost'
      username mysql_connection_info[:username]
      password mysql_connection_info[:password]
      database 'railsreadings_production'
      adapter 'mysql2'
      encoding 'utf8'
    end
  end
  unicorn do
    preload_app true
    port "9000"
    worker_timeout 30
    worker_processes 2
  end
end
```

Even though I have preload_app true, unicorn is not restarted. I can see from the chef log that unicorn's before_compile cook and before_deploy hooks are executed, but it does not go into before_restart. Any pointers about my mistakes in configuration?

Answer (score 1):

The model with the application cookbook is that it will look for a "restart_command" in each of the registered resources and trigger these between the before_restart and after_restart callbacks.  In the previous releases of the application_ruby this would default to "touch tmp/restart.txt" which is the default for passenger.  In the current release there is no default restart_command.

I suggest adding a suitable command for unicorn:

```
application 'railsapp' do
  ...
  restart_command "service unicorn restart"
  ...
end
```

Depending on the version of the application_ruby cookbook, you may need to put this under the "rails" resource.

We use these cookbooks extensively at [Ninefold](http://ninefold.com) in our rails app deployment service and generally they work very well. We find the actual callbacks very useful to over-ride the inbuilt actions such as migrations and asset precompilation to provide better control and reporting.